# Velocity.js // Opacity problems

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, velocity.js

Having some velocity.js problems with opacity

for example, in the css file :

```
#background{ opacity: .5 }
```

and the ***coffee script*** part :

```
$("#backgound").velocity(
  opacity: 0
, 350)
```

velocity won't be of any effect. Same goes with background color : if for example `#background{ background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) }`, changing the background color through velocity won't be of any effects neither

Any feedback appreciated on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [[ EXAMPLE ]](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lhzEp)
I did what you want with both `opacity` and `backgroundColor`.
Velocity not supporting `rgba()` yet, but you can use `backgroundColor` with `HEX` unit and change its transparency by `backgroundColorAlpha`.

Good Luck

Comment: backgroundColorAlpha ! got it. should have gone through the whole docs, thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to use brackets -->

$("#backgound").velocity({
  opacity: 0
}, 350)

Answer (score 0):

try this :
braket forgetting!!

```
$div.velocity({
    properties: { opacity: 1 },
    options: { duration: 500 }
});
```

http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Comment: damn sorry, its just coffee script right up so well, its pretty much how its written with it. The thing is with velocity, you can just go from 1 to 0 and from 0 to 1, but not from 0.5 to 0 and from 0 to 0.5… or at least it does not work on my side

Comment: np.
i use CSS3 fade effect.(Pure CSS3)
its very fast and without lag.
but sometimes not match with jquary!

Comment: yep, pure css effects for this works. but you might agree that we'll all be happier to have all animations in a single place (and in my case i'd like to  move it all to velocity)